How do I project a 2d function into 3d space?
lets say I wanna draw a 2d function in 3d like f(x) = x². f(x,z) = x² will give me a whole plane in the space. But I only want a thin line with a non variable y. So that a have a function that is only a thin line in 3d.
f(x,y) = x^2
Would I find it if wrote that function in a vector like v1=(x,3,f(x)) with x=x, 3=y, z=f(x)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If I am reading your confusing question correctly, I think you have solved your own problem by reinventing the idea of a parameterized curve in space. As $x$ varies over the real numbers the point $(x,3,x^2)$ traces a parabola in space that lives in the plane where $y=3$.
It would be more traditional to name the input variable "$t$" and write the curve as
$$
f(t) = (t, 3, t^2).
$$
The $t$ suggests   tracing out a curve in space as    $t$ime goes on.

Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

You're welcome. The way to thank folks on this site is to accept the answer (the check mark) and upvote it (the up arrow).
